# How to programatically change a link's state to :active?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a link:

```
<a id="link-50" href="#">MyLink</a>
```

I have some css defined for it's active state:

```css
#link-50
{
  color:#eee;
}
#link-50:active
{
 color:#ddd;
}
```

I want to programatically change the color of link-50 to #ddd, i.e., I'm trying to change the link to go to it's active state.  I thought calling the click() event would do that, but it doesn't seem to change the color.

I tried this:

```
#link-50.click();
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it directly but you can use a class

```css
#link-50:active, #link-50.active
{
    color:#ddd;
}
```

Then toggle it with *jQuery*

```
$('#link-50').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    // or...
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // or...
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: why the double sentence at: `#link-50:active, #link-50.active` ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales Because we want to keep the native behaviour of the link when its activated

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the link will change it to `active` and then `visited`. Note, the `active` state is generally a `mousedown` state. Once the mouse if released, links go to `visited`, buttons are no longer active, etc. (see this [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7sJCj/)).

The best way to handle this would be to add a class to toggle on and off programmtically, which would apply the color:

```
$('#link-50').toggleClass('active'); // turn color on/off
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sJCj/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
$('#link-50').trigger('click');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ (Trigger jQuery)